# Dimension of most fibers of $X^m \to Y^n$ of irreducible $k$ varieties are pure dimension $m-n$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading Ravi Vakil's [notes on algebraic geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf) and in Theorem 11.4.1 he claims: "Suppose $\pi: X \to Y$ is a (necessarily finite type) morphism of irreducible $k$-varieties with $dim X = m,$ and $ dim Y = n$. Then there exists a nonempty open subset $U \subset Y$ such that for all $q \in U,$ the fiber over $q$ has pure dimension $m-n$." He quickly reduces to the affine case $\pi: Spec(A) \to Spec(B)$ with $\pi$ dominant and claims that it suffices to show there is a distinguished open subset $U \subset Spec(B)$ for which the restriction factors through $\pi^{-1}(U) \to \mathbb{A}^{m-n}_U \to U$ where $\mathbb{A}^{m-n}_U := \mathbb{A}_k^{m-n} \times U$ and $\psi: \pi^{-1}(U) \to \mathbb{A}^{m-n}_U$ is a finite surjection.

In particular, he argues that using the fact that codimension is the difference of dimension for varieties and the fact that for any morphism with $\pi(p) = q, codim_Xp \leq codim_Yq + codim_{\pi^{-1}(q)}p$, we can argue that **any component** of the fiber over a point of $U$ has dimension at least $m-n$. While I agree we can show this for some component, what precisely is stopping a situation like $\mathbb{A}^2_k \coprod \mathbb{A}^1_k \to \mathbb{A}^2_k$ from happening?

I looked in other books but none seemed to specifically address the **pure** dimension part of this statement.

Comment: Is your domain irreducible? Ravi demands it.

Comment: Yes! We have $X$ is irreducible. Over an algebraically closed field then we’d have each fiber is irreducible, but we don’t have irreduciblilty necessarily.

Comment: I don’t see why we have irreducibility of each fiber*

Comment: I am sorry, I do not see how the disjoint union of $\mathbb{A}^2$ and $\mathbb{A}^1$ is irreducible. What am I missing?

Comment: It's not. My specific question is "Is it possible for the fiber of a morphism to be reducible where the components have different dimensions, even though the domain is irreducible?"

The map $Spec(\mathbb{C}) \to Spec(\mathbb{R})$ base changed by itself shows it's possible to base change and obtain a reducible scheme.

Comment: Some fibers may indeed be reducible with different dimensional components. General fiber will not have this problem.

Comment: @TomGannon did you ever figure this question out? I'm trying to solve it now but I'm confused about similar things. I've shown that $\dim(W) \leq m-n$ for any irreducible component of the fibre but the other inequality is eluding me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I went through the entire proof and worked with the specific construction used in the proof later and proved it from there. I wrote it down, but I left that notebook at home and I am out of town! Will update this by Saturday 3/10/2018.

Comment: @TomGannon Cool! I'd love to see it when you get some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to figure it out! It's corollary 2.

**Lemma**: If $\pi :X\to Y$ is a morphism of schemes and $\pi(x) = y$ for some $x \in X$ then the map $O_{X,x}/x \to O_{\pi^{-1}(y), x}/x$ induced by the map of schemes $\pi^{-1}(y) \to X$ is an isomorphism.

*Proof of Lemma*: Pick an affine open $Spec(B) \subset Y$ containing Y and similarly choose an affine open $Spec(A) \subset \pi^{-1}(Spec(B))$ containing $x$. By abuse of notation, identify $x, y$ as prime ideals of $A, B$ respectively. Then base changing the map $y \to Spec(B)$ is the composite $Spec(B_y/y) \to Spec(B_y) \to Spec(B)$ and base changing this map by $Spec(A) \to Spec(B)$, the domain $\pi^{-1}(y)$ is $Spec(A \otimes_BB_y/y) \cong Spec(A/(\pi^{\sharp}(y)) \otimes_BB_y) \cong Spec((A/(\pi^{\sharp}(y))_{\pi^{\sharp}(B\setminus y)})$.

Then the map of local rings is the map $A_x/x \to ((A/\pi^{\sharp}(y))_{\pi^{\sharp}(B\setminus y)})_{x}/x = ((A/\pi^{\sharp}(y))_x/x$. Note though that this map is a surjection of fields, and thus an isomorphism.

**Corollary 1**: If $\pi : X \to Y$ is a morphism of integral $k-$schemes for some field $k$ and $\pi(x) = y$ then $dim_X\overline{\{x\}} = dim_Y\overline{\{y\}} + dim_{\pi^{-1}(y)}\overline{\{x\}}$.

*Proof of Corollary 1*: By the lemma, the map $O_{X,x}/x \to O_{\pi^{-1}(y), x}/x$ is an isomorphism. Also note that finite type $k-$schemes are preserved by base change so if $l := O_{Y,y}/y$, then $\pi^{-1}(y)$ is a finite type $l$-scheme. Thus because $l \to O_{\pi^{-1}(y), x}/x \cong O_{X, x}$ we have

$$dim_X\overline{\{x\}} = tr.deg(O_{X,x}/x, k) = tr.deg(O_{X,x}/x, l) + tr.deg(l, k) = dim_{\pi^{-1}(y)}\overline{\{x\}} + dim_Y\overline{\{y\}}.$$

**Corollary 2**:  If $\pi : X \to Y$ is a morphism of integral $k-$schemes for some field $k$ then for each $y \in Y$ each irreducible component of $\pi^{-1}(y)$ has dimension $\geq dim(X) - dim(Y)$.

*Proof of Corollary 2*: Let $x$ be a generic point of an irreducible component of $\pi^{-1}(y)$. Then by Vakil 11.4.A. (linked above) we have $codim_X\overline{\{x\}} \leq codim_Y\overline{\{y\}} + codim_{\pi^{-1}(y)}\overline{\{x\}} = codim_Y\overline{\{y\}}$. Since for irreducible $k$ varieties codimension is the difference of dimension, we obtain

$$dim(X) - dim(Y) \leq dim_X\overline{\{x\}} - dim_Y\overline{\{y\}} = dim_{\pi^{-1}(y)}\overline{\{y\}},$$

as desired!

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! The algebra showing the stalk at $x$ in the fibre $\pi^{-1}(y)$ is a quotient of the stalk in $X$ is tricky but I'm convinced. The rest of the argument is very clear.

Comment: @ggg another way to see the lemma:  $\pi^{-1}(y)\to X$ is given locally by localization followed by a quotient, $ R\to R[U^{-1}]\to R[U^{-1}]/I$.  The map of stalks of the composition is given by the composition of the map of stalks.  But the second map is already surjective, and it is easy to see that any map of stalks induced by the first map is also surjective.  So the map of stalks is surjective and so passing to the quotient by the unique maximal ideals gives a surjective map.

Comment: @Tom I have corrected a few typos and made a couple of editorial changes. Please feel free to revert any or all

Comment: By the way, @Tom, I know it's been a while since you posted this, but do you happen to remember what is the relevance of making sure $\psi: \pi^{-1}(U) \to \mathbb{A}^{m-n}_U$ is *surjective*?  In the proof of the exercise I seemed only to use that it is finite.